# Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`: (NoMethodError) with launching to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm an intermediate Rails developer and I am using a remote database as my sole connection in a production environment. My stack is Rails 5 and Ruby 2.4.0. I have already set the environment variables up for the database such as USERNAME and PASSWORD. When I deploy to Heroku I get this error message:

```
Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`: (NoMethodError)
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm assuming this is because that Rails can't see the environment variables, but even when I hard coded the username and password for the database for testing the same error occurs.

Here's my database.yml

```
default: &default
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    pool: 5


socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
  reconnect: true

development:
  <<: *default
    database: hittrax_tournaments_development
    username: root
    password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>

test:
  <<: *default
  database: hittrax_tournaments_test
  username: root
  password: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:password] %>

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['HOST'] %>
  port: 3306
```

Here's the stack trace

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:51: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:52: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:138: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
(erb):12:in `<main>': Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`: (NoMethodError)
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/erb.rb:896:in `eval'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/erb.rb:896:in `result'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:137:in `database_configuration'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:122:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `instance_eval'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `execute_hook'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:324:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /app/app/models/application_record.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `block in require_or_load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:150:in `exclusive'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:358:in `require_or_load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:336:in `depend_on'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `require_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `block in eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:354:in `eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:157:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:77:in `console'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /app/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem comes from this line in your `test` environment section:

```
<%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:password] %>
```

When Rails boots up, it loads `config/database.yml` and parse the whole file with the `ERB` gem before `YAML.load`. So every erb code will be executed no matter which environment you are running. When the ERB parser comes to the above line, it tries to reads the value of `:password` from 
`Rails.application.secrets[:database]`. When there's no `:database` section under the corresponding environment key, `Rails.application.secrets[:database]` becomes `nil` and calling `[:password]` on it gives you the error

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

You can add `database:` under each environment key in `config/secrets.yml` to fix this problem. Or replace the nested `secrets[:database][:password]` structure with a flat structure `secrets[:database_password]`. Or remove the line which is causing the problem.

You can check the `database_configuration` method in `/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb` for more detail.

Comment: I had this happen to me. The offending line (which was trying to access a non-existent variable) had been commented out, yet it was throwing this `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Neat explanation!! And also I had the same problem that @jedi.jesse had: The offending statement was commented out.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with the YAML file format, indentation matters. You have a few different indentation levels going on.

Also, it looks like you're missing a key for the "test" environment.

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
  reconnect: true

development:
  <<: *default
  database: hittrax_tournaments_development
  username: root
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>

test:
  <<: *default
  database: hittrax_tournaments_test
  username: root
  password: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:password] %>

production:
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['HOST'] %>
  port: 3306
```

Also, for reference, here's what I get when running `rails new hittrax -d mysql`:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: hittrax_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: hittrax_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: hittrax_production
  username: hittrax
  password: <%= ENV['HITTRAX_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Comment: Hey Richard, I changed my database.yml file to match your solution and I still get the same error. Would you need any extra information from me for any error checking?

Comment: If you could update your original post with the full stack trace, that would be helpful.